# NBodySimulation softening parameter

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages, physics, simulation

I'm simulating the orbit of a binary black hole immersed in some halo of particles and the simulation does not want to continue on for the specified amount of time. It always halts at a seemingly arbitrary time, with the following error:

```
NDSolve`Iterate::mxst: Maximum number of 10000 steps reached at the point \[FormalT] == 7.660456531497224`*^11.
```

The relevant code is:

```
n = 10;
BHsemimajaxis = 
  QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity[10^-8, "Parsecs"], "Meters"]];
BHmass = QuantityMagnitude[
   UnitConvert[Quantity[30, "SolarMass"], "Kilograms"]];
vel = QuantityMagnitude@
   UnitConvert[
    Sqrt[(Quantity["GravitationalConstant"]*
      Quantity[BHmass, "Kilograms"])/
     Quantity[BHsemimajaxis, "Parsecs"]], ("Meters")/("Seconds")];
time = Quantity[100, "Kiloyears"];
keys = {"Mass", "Position", "Velocity"};
Masses = Table[10^1, {i, 1, n}];
Positions = RandomReal[{-BHsemimajaxis, BHsemimajaxis}, {n, 3}];
Velocitys = RandomReal[{-5, 5}, {n, 3}];
initialdata = {Masses, Positions, Velocitys};
initialdataassoc = 
  Table[Association@
    Table[keys[[i]] -> initialdata[[i]][[k]], {i, 1, 3}], {k, 1, n}];
BH1 = <|"Mass" -> BHmass, "Position" -> {0, -BHsemimajaxis, 0}, 
   "Velocity" -> {vel, 0, 0}|>;
BH2 = <|"Mass" -> BHmass, "Position" -> {0, BHsemimajaxis, 0}, 
   "Velocity" -> {-vel, 0, 0}|>;
AppendTo[initialdataassoc, BH1];
AppendTo[initialdataassoc, BH2];

data = NBodySimulation["Newtonian",
   initialdataassoc, time];
```

and if you would like to animate the result:

```
plotran = QuantityMagnitude@ BHsemimajaxis*1.2;
timeslice[t_] := If[n > 0,
  
  Block[{}, pnts1 = data[Table[i, {i, 1, n}], "Position", t];
   pnts2 = data[Table[i, {i, n + 1, n + 2}], "Position", t];
   obj1 = {Blue, Scale[Sphere[], plotran/40]};
   obj2 = {Black, Scale[Sphere[], plotran/20]};
   Graphics3D[{Translate[obj1, pnts1], Translate[obj2, pnts2]}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-plotran, plotran}, {-plotran, plotran}, {-plotran,
        plotran}}]],
  
  Block[{},
   pnts2 = data[Table[i, {i, n + 1, n + 2}], "Position", t];
   obj2 = {Black, Scale[Sphere[], plotran/20]};
   Graphics3D[{Translate[obj2, pnts2]}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-plotran, plotran}, {-plotran, plotran}, {-plotran,
        plotran}}]]
  ]
Animate[
 timeslice[t], {t, 0, 
  QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[time, "Seconds"]] - 1},
 AnimationRate -> 2*10^11]
```

I believe this is due to the lack of a softening length for the field equations, but I'm not exactly sure how to incorporate such a softening length. If this is indeed the problem, how could I incorporate a softening parameter?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: For me your example produces `NDSolve`Iterate::ndsz: At t == 190.82940054286775`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected` which is consistent with the behaviour described in documentation says (https://wolfram.com/xid/0bh1yrtrwcf5ua-n3t0eo) and to visualisation produced by `ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[data[All, "Position", t]], {t, 0, 190}]`.

Will you please check your code in a fresh kernel (after Quit[])?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to turn on the surrounding halo for the black holes by changing ```n=0``` to ```n=10```. Turning it one produces the same error (with different numerical value of the time). The error must be showing up because particles in the halo are colliding with each other or the black hole. I think introducing a softening parameter would avoid this issue, but I'm not sure how to specify a custom potential field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to add a softening parameter to the Newtonian field equations.
Instead of specifying `"Newtonian"` in the first argument of `NBodySimulation`, I instead create a new potential function, which I call `potential` and write
`<|"PairwisePotential" -> potential|>`, where the new potential function takes in two particle data sets, which are themselves associations. For my specific example above, this is

```
\[Epsilon]=(*some small number constrained by the scales of the problem*)
potential[p1_, p2_] :=
  
 With[{norm = (Dot[p1["Position"] - p2["Position"], 
       p1["Position"] - p2["Position"]] + \[Epsilon]^2)^(1/2)},
  -((Quantity["GravitationalConstant"]*p1["Mass"]*p2["Mass"])/norm)
  ]
```

where `\[Epsilon]` is the softening parameter commonly found in N-Body Simulations. So, the simulation is then ran with

```
data = NBodySimulation[<|"PairwisePotential" -> potential|>,
   initialdataassoc, time]
```

This can be seen to match the equations of motion for `"Newtonian"`, found via `data["Equations"]`, when `\[Epsilon]-> 0` as expected.

This is basically stated in the documentation for `NBodySimulation`, but I couldn't really figure out what the functional form for the custom potential field should be. So I hope this helps someone else!